# Navigate to new page after logged in

Tags: vbscript

Currently, I have this auto-login script:

```
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
call WshShell.Run("website.com", 1, false) 

WScript.Sleep 2000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "username"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "password"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
WScript.Sleep 1000
REM call WshShell.Run("http://website.com/pageineedtogoto", 1, false)

WScript.Quit()
```

Now I just need it to navigate to a new page but stay in the same tab.

By the way, all of this is plain, client-side VBScript, not in HTML or anything.

Comment: The F6 key will move the cursor to the URL field on almost every browser, so just do a SendKeys to send an F6, the URL, and Enter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Alt+D` sets the focus to the address bar and highlights the text in all major browsers.

```
WshShell.SendKeys "%d"
WshShell.SendKeys "http://website.com/pageineedtogoto"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

You should really look into automating the [`InternetExplorer.Application`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752084%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class instead, however.